# Is it possible to use more than 32 layers in blender VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm editing a video for a project in school and I thought Blender would allow you to use (theoretically) infinite layers, but it caps at 32. Why is that? I can't find anything on it online or even in the Blender docs (it's probably in there somewhere, but i'm probably blind) I don't think it's a bug either unless it is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why there are only 32 channels available; even though you can see more channels.

You can however work around it by using meta strips. Select a few strips and right click. Choose "Make meta strip". Shortcut = Ctrl + G. The selected strips collapse into one channel and count also as 1 channel. This way you can have more than 32 channels.

PS From version 3.0 on, the limit is increased to 128 channels (see https://developer.blender.org/rB8fecc2a85254)

Answer (score 1):

Whats the scenario where you would need more than 32 channels. are you composing a lot of different audio tracks/strips? or multiple movie strips that also has a transparant background.
..Could you in advance render the strips(sound/images) you need, export it and later import it into the VSE you are working on.